# parsing whitespace-separated fields

Tags: powershell, split, type-conversion

Im trying to write a script which works as follows:

My input is a text file with 8 rows and 8 columns, filled with values `0` or `1`, with a single space character each separating the columns.

I need to check the 4th number in each row, and output `false`, if it is `0`, and `true`, if it is `1`.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
param($fname)
$rows = (Get-Content $fname)
for ($i=0;$i -lt $rows.Length;$i++)
{ 
 if ($rows[$i][6] -eq 1)
  {
   Write-Host "true"
  }
 if ($rows[$i][6] -ne 1)
  {
    Write-Host "false"
  }
}
```

So I use `[$i][6]`, because I get that that's the 4th number, accounting for the number of spaces acting as separators.

I checked and thought it was perfect, but somehow it says `false` for *every* line, but when I `Write-Host` `$rows[0][6]` it is `1`.

Comment: `1` -> `'1'[0]`

Comment: You're comparing an integer with a character. Try running `$rows[$i][6].GetType()` to see the type that PS is using for your data. You can also remove the last `if` and change it to an `else` since if it's not 1 it's false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# Create sample input file, with values of interest in 4th field
# (0-based field index 3).
@'
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
'@ > file

foreach ($line in (Get-Content file)) {
    $fields = -split $line
    if ($fields[3] -eq '1') { 
        "true"
    } else {
        "false"
    }
}
```

yields:

```
false
true
```

---

There are many subtleties to consider in your original code, but the above code:

- offers a more `awk`-like approach by splitting each input line into *whitespace-separated fields*, whatever the length of the fields, courtesy of the *unary `-split` operator*.
- subscripts (indices) can then be based on *field* indices rather than *character positions*.
- All fields returned by `-split ...` are *strings*, hence the comparison with *string* literal `'1'`, but, generally, PowerShell performs a lot of behind-the-scenes conversion magic for you: with the code above - unlike with your own code - using `1` would have worked too.

---

As for **why your approach failed**:

- Indexing into (using a subscript with) a *string* value in PowerShell is a special case: it implicitly treats the string as a *character array*, and, with a single index such as `6`, returns a `[char]` instance.
- It is the *LHS* (left-hand side) of an expression involving a binary operator such as `-eq` that determines what type the *RHS* (right-hand side) will be *coerced to*, if necessary, before applying the operator:

  - `([char] '1') -eq 1 # !! $false`

    - Coercing the (implied) `[int]` type of RHS `1` to the LHS type `[char]` yields Unicode *codepoint* `U+0001`, i.e., a *control character* rather than the "ASCII" digit '`1`', which is why the comparison fails.
    - @PetSerAl's helpful, but cryptic suggestion (in a comment on the question) to use `'1'[0]` rather than `1` as the RHS solves the problem in this particular case, because `'1'[0]` returns `1` as a `[char]` instance, but the solution doesn't generalize to *multi-character* field values.
  - `'1' -eq 1 # $true; same as: ([string] 1) -eq 1 or ([string] 1) -eq '1'`

    - Converting integer `1` to a *string* indeed is the same as `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

This script fills a true 2d array with the proper values from the matrix file, but the output doesn't fit.

```
$Array = New-Object "bool[,]"  8,8
[int]$i=0 ; [int]$j=0
get-content $fname|foreach{ foreach ($b in ($_ -split(' '))) {  
        "{0},{1}={2}" -f $i,$j,($b -eq 0)
        $Array[$i,$j] = ($b -eq 0)
        $j++}
  $j=0; $i++}
```